# ElasticSearch facet_filter on multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I am trying to filter my facets on multiple values, it works on single one:

```
"facet_filter": {
    "term": {
      "function":"value_1"
    }
}
```

but what I am trying to do is to filter on multiple values ideally with boolean control(and/or)

```
"facet_filter": {
    "term": {
      "function": [
        "value_1",
        "value_2"
      ]
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this ? I found similar question but actually it does not explain what list(id) is. Any clues ? 
[filtering facets in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231727/filtering-facets-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: `list(ids)` is quite likely a method returning a JSON list of ids (array) that the OP of the referenced question wants to filter.

Comment: Have you used terms?? instead of term??

Comment: Thanks @BlackPOP terms instead of term solved my problem. So now my query looks as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to my problem was as suggested to use terms instead of term.

Posted full request below as I could not find so might be beneficial to others who are searching for same answer.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "syslog.log_key": "time"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "facets": {
    "tag": {
      "terms_stats": {
        "key_field": "function",
        "value_field": "log_value"
      },
      "facet_filter": {
        "terms": {
          "function": [
            "query_parser",
            "term_highlighter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```